# IIS -> Isapi_Redirect -> Tomcat

Tags: iis, tomcat, isapi, isapi-redirect

I've been trying for days to get Tomcat up and running through IIS via the Jakarta Connector.

I've followed all of Microsoft's instructions -- put the connector .dll in %tomcatdir%\bin\win32\i386\, added the registry entry, added a filter (pointing to the .dll) to the default web site... and yet, any time I try to access a Tomcat web app, I get the "You are not authorized to view this page" error.

Has anyone experienced this?  Help!

Thanks,
-Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/win32/jk-1.2.14/isapi_redirect-1.2.14.exe

I use this redirect with Tomcat 5.5 and IIS 5 or 6.  I haven't tried it with IIS 7.

You have to modify the uriworkermap.properties file to choose which paths to redirect, but besides that it works pretty much straight up.  It adds all the registry garbage for you.

Ah, except on IIS 6 you have to add the isapi redirect.dll into its application whitelist.

Comment: No problem.  Follow up if it gives you any trouble, but it should "just work".

Comment: newer versions are available, just browse http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/

Answer (score 1):

Try this mate, it can help you.

http://itgration.blogspot.com/2016/04/configuring-tomcat-connector-for-iis-8.html

It tells you how to configure access to tomcat website via IIS and the necessary to set up tomcat server as a windows service and then forward the website to IIS via port 80. You will do this by installing a custom ISAPI filter in IIS that understands how to use the AJP protocol (Apache JServ Protocol) to communicate with tomcat. The main idea is to use Tomcat Connector ISAPI available to download from apache web site.
I used it with IIS 8 and 7